# Create combinations by group and sum

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, combinations

I have data of names within an ID number along with a number of associated values. It looks something like this:

```
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "b", "b"), name = c("bob", "jane", 
"mark", "brittney"), number = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), value = c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

#   id     name number value
# 1  a      bob      1     1
# 2  a     jane      2     2
# 3  b     mark      1     1
# 4  b brittney      2     2
```

I would like to create all the combinations of `name`, regardless of how many there are, and paste them together separated with commas, and sum their `number` and `value` within each `id`. The desired output from the example above is then:

```
structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"), name = c("bob", 
"jane", "bob, jane", "mark", "brittney", "mark, brittney"), number = c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L), value = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))

#   id           name number value
# 1  a            bob      1     1
# 2  a           jane      2     2
# 3  a      bob, jane      3     3
# 4  b           mark      1     1
# 5  b       brittney      2     2
# 6  b mark, brittney      3     3
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create pairwise indices using `combn()` and expand the data frame with these using `slice()`. Then just group by these row pairs and summarise. I'm assuming you want pairwise combinations but this can be adapted for larger sets if needed.  Some code to handle groups < 2 is included but can be removed if these don't exist in your data.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

df1 %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  slice(c(combn(seq(n()), min(n(), 2)))) %>%
  mutate(id2 = (row_number()-1) %/% 2) %>%
  group_by(id, id2) %>%
  summarise(name = toString(name),
            across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = "drop") %>%
  select(-id2) %>%
  bind_rows(df1 %>%
              group_by(id) %>%
              filter(n() > 1), .) %>%
  arrange(id) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  id    name           number value
  <chr> <chr>           <int> <int>
1 a     bob                 1     1
2 a     jane                2     2
3 a     bob, jane           3     3
4 b     mark                1     1
5 b     brittney            2     2
6 b     mark, brittney      3     3
```

**Edit:**

To adapt for all possible combinations you can iterate over the values up to the max group size. Using edited data which has a couple of rows added to the first group:

```
map_df(seq(max(table(df2$id))), ~
         df2 %>%
         group_by(id) %>%
         slice(c(combn(seq(n()), .x * (.x <= n())))) %>%
         mutate(id2 = (row_number() - 1) %/% .x) %>%
         group_by(id, id2) %>%
         summarise(name = toString(name),
                   across(where(is.numeric), sum), .groups = "drop")
       ) %>%
  select(-id2) %>%
  arrange(id)

# A tibble: 18 × 4
   id    name                      number value
   <chr> <chr>                      <int> <int>
 1 a     bob                            1     1
 2 a     jane                           2     2
 3 a     sophie                         1     1
 4 a     jeremy                         2     2
 5 a     bob, jane                      3     3
 6 a     bob, sophie                    2     2
 7 a     bob, jeremy                    3     3
 8 a     jane, sophie                   3     3
 9 a     jane, jeremy                   4     4
10 a     sophie, jeremy                 3     3
11 a     bob, jane, sophie              4     4
12 a     bob, jane, jeremy              5     5
13 a     bob, sophie, jeremy            4     4
14 a     jane, sophie, jeremy           5     5
15 a     bob, jane, sophie, jeremy      6     6
16 b     mark                           3     5
17 b     brittney                       4     6
18 b     mark, brittney                 7    11
```

Data for `df2`:

```
df2 <- structure(list(id = c("a", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b"), name = c("bob", 
                                                                     "jane", "sophie", "jeremy", "mark", "brittney"), number = c(1L, 
                                                                                                                                 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), value = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                              -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you! This is great, clever. I do need all combinations of `names`, not just pairwise, within each `id` (apologies for the too-minimal example). So changing that is lines 3 and 4? Did you have a specific tweak in mind?

Comment: Can you expand on your expected output?  If for example a group contained 4 names, would you want the output to contain 4 (single) + 6 (pair combination) + 4 (triplet combinations) + 1 (quad)  rows (i.e. 15 rows for that group)?

Comment: @BHudson - see edit.

Comment: Thank you! I really appreciate the help. This is super clever and something I will learn a lot from.

Answer (score 5):

You could use `group_modify()` + `add_row()`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  group_modify( ~ .x %>%
    summarise(name = toString(name), across(c(number, value), sum)) %>%
    add_row(.x, .)
  ) %>%
  ungroup()

# # A tibble: 6 × 4
#   id    name           number value
#   <chr> <chr>           <int> <int>
# 1 a     bob                 1     1
# 2 a     jane                2     2
# 3 a     bob, jane           3     3
# 4 b     mark                1     1
# 5 b     brittney            2     2
# 6 b     mark, brittney      3     3
```

Comment: I don't think this solves OPs problem - they're asking for combinations of cases.  OPs example data and output was perhaps a bit too minimal.

Comment: @RitchieSacramento Yes, maybe. A simplified description of questions leads to a simplified answer. Thanks for the useful comment.

Comment: Thanks Darren! Apologies for the too minimal example. This is great though. Yes; I need all combinations of `names` within each `id`, so I don't think this will work. Upvoted and appreciated though!

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  lapply(
    .SD,
    function(x) {
      unlist(
        lapply(
          seq_along(x),
          combn,
          x = x,
          function(v) {
            ifelse(all(is.character(v)), toString, sum)(v)
          }
        )
      )
    }
  ),
  id
]
```

gives

```
   id           name number value
1:  a            bob      1     1
2:  a           jane      2     2
3:  a      bob, jane      3     3
4:  b           mark      1     1
5:  b       brittney      2     2
6:  b mark, brittney      3     3
```

Comment: This is great! Thank you! Upvoted. Works and generalizes to cases with many values for `names`. I already accepted the other answer but will learn from this and it is great to have for others' future reference.